# Django Template Styling

Tags: django-templates

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
            <p style="font-size: 12pt; color: #000">{{ post }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the code in my template. It appears on my site with a white background. I want it to be black. I tryed it with css and styleing the div or putting it in another div thats black but it just won't do. How am I suppose to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
in your template put:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center black">
        <p style="font-size: 12pt; color: #000">{{ post }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

with the new CSS class `black`:

```
<style>
.black {
  background-color: black !important;
}
</style>
```